# How to Update Contact field based on what Title Contains without hardcoding

Tags: apex, trigger

We have a trigger that will update Contact Team based on if condition. In if condition we will check if contact title contains X then Contact team should be B. We have a lot of conditions like this and we don't want to hardcode it. Is there is any simple way to do it?

Comment: You can define your fix sets of data in Custom Setting. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_customsettings.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom metadata to store the the condition and the corresponding team. If you use custom metadata, it will be easy for you to transfer the data while production deployment.

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/341151/when-loading-bulk-data-i-am-getting-error-apex-cpu-limit-exceeded/341166#341166 this is my code ... can you please help me to solve the issue